# How to Apply WebPack in Angluar Project?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, bundling-and-minification, angular12

To make an angular project work Efficiently  one of the effective way is bundling, Web-pack Bundling seems to be a good option , but cant able to find articles for integrating web-pack with Angular Project , Can some one help ?

Comment: Angular is already bundling with webpack

Comment: yes, but adding a custom webpack provides additional configuration option to make project more efficient

Comment: Then you are looking to simply configure the webpack used by angular. You can read about that everywhere. I suggest you check out the npm pacakge @angular-builders/custom-webpack

Comment: I would recommend using Angular CLI. https://angular.io/cli. Projects created with CLI already uses webpack created by the angular team. This already has optimization required for maximum efficiency. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha maybe he wants to work with webpack bcs of module federation ?? Otherwise it makes no sense to me.